# How to add default icon in Qt widget application

Tags: application-development, qt

I am trying to develop a simple qt app, I would like icon for the toolbar buttons, How can I standard icons for these toolbar buttons, new,open,close etc

Comment: This questions isn't duplicate

Comment: "How can I standard icons"???? I don't know how can you "standard" something. Could you be more specific and shows us the attempts/results? Have you tried the part of the answer that says "To use the icons in your code"?